# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results - V2

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #5](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/5) on English Language Learners has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: gotube]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

After talking with Void, who has chosen to step down, we're calling up the next candidate in the election following our process - we re-ran the election with two slots to identify the second choice candidate. For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/5) or [view the updated summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5724914192482304).

Comment: Is this the appropriate place to ask about opavote? In this election it transferred excess votes from the first winner to the other candidates (in round 2), but how does it decide whose votes are in excess? Some people may have had candidate X as second choice and others might have had candidate Y.

Comment: @Luc it distributed them proportionally as a factor of all votes cast for Void. That's why you see fractional votes.

Answer (score 10):

Congratulations gotube! I was impressed by the thoughtfulness of your answers to all of the community's questions, both on the official questionnaire and the ones asked during the voting. I know you'll be a great mod for ELL.

Comment: Thanks so much Colleen! Glad to be on board